# Creating a Table from a list of objects c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class-library

I have  Class of people that look like this:

```
    class Person
{
    public string firstName { get; }
    public string lastName { get; }
    public int age { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstName,string lastName, int age)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to create a table from a list of persons that I can send via email that looks like this:

[image]

how can I do it ?

thanks

Comment: This isn't a data table, and your class have a different name for it's constructor. Please [edit] your question to provide a correct example.

Comment: did so, can you have a look ?

Comment: Probably the OP refers to an HTML Table but again, we need  more clarity in the question.

Comment: @Steve I agree. "send via email" is a dead giveaway.

Comment: This is way too broad. You need to at least try to implement this yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("firstname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("lastname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("age", typeof(int));

            foreach (Person person in people)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { person.firstName, person.lastName, person.age });
            }

        }
    }
    class Person
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set;  }
        public int age { get; set; }

        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
}
```